# PHP While - SELECT html tag

Tags: php, select, loops, while-loop

I have an issue, I just cannot solve. I have a PHP script, which loops my membership packages from my database. I have now 5 membership packages, to 3 different memberships.

I want a SELECT option. So users can select what package they want, to each membership.

But when I tries to do a while loop, and loop it out, it just loops out ALL 5 membership packages. I want 3 SELECTs, with the membership package details inside.

My current code:

```
                                <?php
                                $p=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM membership_packages");
                                while($mp = mysql_fetch_assoc($p)):
                                    echo '      <select>
                                                <option>'.$mp['duration'].' Days</option>
                                                 </select>
                                          ';

                                endwhile;
                            ?>
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to be more specific in your SQL SELECT query.  What does this query currently return?  How do you want to further filter that down?

Comment: I don't know how to be more specific in the sql query. Because I show ALL the memberships via the while loop, so I cannot set an unique ID in the SQL command.

Comment: Can we see the schema for 'membership_packages'? It's hard to answer data-specific questions without seeing the data!

Comment: You can see my DB here: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0d2i6dae0

Comment: Can you explain what the difference is between a membership and a membership package?

Comment: I'm still unclear on what you want to do here.  You have 5 records in this table and you want to group them into 3 groupings?  How are these groupings differentiated?

Comment: Sorry, I also have a table named memberships (Here are 3 memberships located).

Comment: you really need to add more information to your question, e.g. the relations between your membership table and your membership packages. Are all packages related to a specific membership or only three of them and the other two are unrelated and have an empty membershipid?

Answer (score 0):

Either do the limit as someone else suggested or (if you want the logic only way of doing it, e.g you dont know mysql) you can use and a iteration counter to stop the while loop something like:

```
i = 0 ;
while($mp = mysql_fetch_assoc($p) && i <=2):

echo '      <select>
<option>'.$mp['duration'].' Days</option>
</select>
  ';
 i++;

endwhile;
```

Edit: went to 4 not 3.

Comment: If you're just going to limit it to 4 values why not just do `LIMIT 4` in the SQL?

Comment: As I said this is for a person curious how to do it with php logic only, without needing to no special sql stuff. Might be useful for him in the future

Answer (score 0):

In addition to NoviceCoding's solution, you most definitely want to pull the opening and closing select tags out of the while loop.  You only want those once but multiple option inside.

```
i = 0 ;
echo '<select>';
while($mp = mysql_fetch_assoc($p) && i <3):
    echo '<option>'.$mp['duration'].' Days</option>';
    i++;
endwhile;
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Hey I had to edit mine so its <=2. This one does 4 iterations

Answer (score 0):

```
<label for="c1">Selcciona la clave:</label>
        <select>
        <?php 
            $i=0;
            $var="10-";
            while ( $i<= 100) {
                echo $var." $i <option>";
                $i = $i + 1;
            }
        ?>
```